# Disable WCF help page for certain endpoints only

Tags: wcf, config, endpoint

I have a WCF REST Service with the help page enabled using the web.config file

> <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />

This works perfectly for the following endpoints (all return similar type of data based on different calculations)

> mysite.com/GetData/{id}
>   mysite.com/GetData/v2/{id}
>   mysite.com/GetData/v3/{id}
>   mysite.com/GetData/v4/{id}

I don't want to expose v3 and v4 help pages to my clients yet and so I tried to disable the help for v3 and v4. Using the instructions in this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/02/01/returning-custom-formats-from-wcf-webhttp-services.aspx as follows:

> <service name="Services.MyService">
>                 <endpoint address="/v3" kind="webHttpEndpoint" 
>                     contract="Services.MyService" endpointConfiguration="EndPointv3"></endpoint>
>                 <endpoint address="/v4" kind="webHttpEndpoint" 
>                     contract="Services.MyService" endpointConfiguration="EndPointv4"></endpoint>
>             </service>

and

> <standardEndpoint name="EndPointv3"/>
>     <standardEndpoint name="EndPointv4"/>

This will not work for me and the help pages appear for all endpoints. However, if I leave the endpoint address empty (address=""), help pages are disabled for all endpoints. Any ideas on how I can disable the help pages for v3 and v4 only?